# React bootstrap table 2 programmatically select filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow this [example](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Column%20Filter&selectedStory=Programmatically%20Select%20Filter&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel). I've pretty much replicated it line for line, adding in 5 products as that data isn't given in the example. Everything displays correctly so in theory I've set it up correctly, however the filter doesn't seem to work like it does in the example.

Any ideas? This is what I have:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mmvhyv?file=Table.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is with `products` data `quality` field and `selectOption` fields , they are is matched

It tries to compare the `products` data `quality` with `selectOption`'s `key`

So either you change `products`

```
const products = [
    {"id": "1", "name":"john", "quality":"unknown"},
    {"id": "2", "name":"jane", "quality":"good"},
    {"id": "3", "name":"bob", "quality":"Bad"},
    {"id": "4", "name":"ralph", "quality":"Bad"},
]
```

To :

```
const products = [
    {"id": "1", "name":"john", "quality":2},
    {"id": "2", "name":"jane", "quality":0},
    {"id": "3", "name":"bob", "quality":1},
    {"id": "4", "name":"ralph", "quality":1},
]
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-table-filter2)**

---

**OR**

change `selectOptions` to :

```
const selectOptions = {
    'good' : 'good',
    'Bad' : 'Bad',
    'unknown' : 'unknown',
};

const handleClick = () => {
    qualityFilter('good'); // <---- here to
};
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-table-filter)**

Answer (score 0):

In case you are calling API and populating your table, you need to check the response data and map it with the text displayed on UI.

For eg:

```
  {
      "ID": 1,
      "CreatedAt": "2021-09-02T04:30:45.37+05:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-09-02T04:30:45.37+05:30",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "Gender":"male",
      "roll_no": 1,
      "first_name": "Ravi",
      "use_transport": false
    }
```

Suppose we want to add select filter on **use_transport** and **Gender**.
Observe that use_transport is boolean as `false` and Gender is string "male" not capitalized. On UI if you are representing this two field as
use_transport="false" and Gender="Male". Then you need to create options map as follows,

```
 const genderSelectOptions = {
        "male": "Male",
        "female": "Female",
        "other": "Other"
    };

  const booleanSelectOptions = {
       true:"true",
       false: "false"
  }
```

The key will be the value coming in response and the value of the map will be the value you are representing on the UI.

**NOTE:** It is important to have one unique ID in your table, you can keep it hidden. Filter uses that ID internally to distinguish the unique record.

The unique key has to be then bind as **keyField** in Bootstrap table tag

```
<BootstrapTable
    striped hover condensed pagination={true} 
    search
    keyField='ID'
    data={this.state.students}
    columns={this.state.columns} 
    filter={filterFactory()}
    pagination={paginationFactory()} />
```